# How to use the csv dataset file imported as a dataframe in QSVM Qiskit code

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-gate

I am trying to run QSVM qiskit code with my custom dataset which I am loading as a pandas dataframe. When I execute the part below with my own dataset in the place of breast_cancer, it gives error " Dataframe object not callable"

```
feature_dim = 2
sample_total, training_input, test_input, class_labels = breast_cancer(
    training_size=20,
    test_size=10,
    n=feature_dim,
    plot_data=True
)
```

Please suggest how do i use my csv file as a dataset for QSVM qiskit code

Answer (score 0):

Qiskit has an inbuilt function for the breast cancer dataset. To utilise your custom dataset, use the `train_test_split` method in sklearn to run the code you described.